# Elasticsearch result in lowercwse

Tags: elasticsearch

> Why elasticsearch return result in lowercase rather than the actual result in database .
>   My query in Elasticsearch is .

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tellofy/_search?pretty' -d ' 
{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"webprivacy":"true"}},{"terms":  {"_id":[]}}],"minimum_should_match":1,"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"name:Sp*"}}]}},"_source":["name"]}'
```

> I got the results for "sp" related results , but all in lowercwse. its not like as it is in DB. what i need to do, to get as it is from DB.

Comment: This is probably because in the mapping of the field 'name', your index uses Standard Analyzer which uses lowercase token filter, meaning all the text will be broken down to lowercase tokens. Standard Analyzer is default for the field if you haven't explicitly specified the mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-analyzer.html). Are you fine with your queries to be case sensitive? If yes, you can provide different analyzer for field name which will not convert tokens to lowercase.

Comment: without changing in mapping , is there any way to use analyser. I tried query_string "lowercase_expanded_terms": false . it does not works for me . can anybody suggest for case-insensitive for my above query.

Comment: It is strange, for me the data is returned in the same case I indexed the data, not lower case, I use elasticsearch 2.3.1. How did you index your data, can you put example? Which version of elasticsearch you use?

Comment: elasticsearch 1.7.2